# Recycler view doesn't update item with livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I have a fragment where use creates a budget for a specific category like this:
[image]

Here is how it works: user adds a new budget item in NewBudgetFragment. That item gets displayed in BudgetFragment in recyclerview. Budget item has amountSpent variable that should be updated each time user adds a new transaction(this happens in another fragment). But after creating the budget item, if the user spends money on that specific category, the amountSpent doesn't get updated in the recyclerview item. I have used both LiveData and DiffUtil in the BudgetAdapter but I can't figure out why it doesn't get updated.

Here is BudgetAdapter:

```
class BudgetAdapter() : ListAdapter<Budget, BudgetAdapter.BudgetViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BudgetViewHolder {
        val binding =
            BudgetItemLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return BudgetViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BudgetViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem, position)
    }

    class BudgetViewHolder(val binding: BudgetItemLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(budget: Budget, position: Int) {
            binding.apply {
                tvBudgetName.text = budget.name
                tvBudgetLimit.text = budget.limit.toString()
                tvAmountSpent.text = budget.amountSpent.toString()
                tvPercentageSpent.text = ((budget.amountSpent/budget.limit)*100).toInt().toString() + "%"
            }
        }
    }

    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Budget>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Budget, newItem: Budget): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Budget, newItem: Budget): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }
}
```

This is how new budget item gets created:
NewBudgetFragment:

```
...
viewModel.transactions.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { it ->
                            transactionList = it.filter { it.category == listCategory[selectedCategoryIndex].name }
                            amountSpent = transactionList.sumOf { it.amount }
                        }
...

if (budgetName.isNotEmpty() && budgetLimit.isNotEmpty() && budgetCategory != null) {
                            viewModel.addBudget(
                                name = budgetName,
                                limit = budgetLimit.toDouble(),
                                amountSpent=amountSpent,
                                category = budgetCategory.name)
```

This is BudgetFragment.kt where the adapter is:

```
class BudgetFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_budget),BudgetAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentBudgetBinding
    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentBudgetBinding.bind(view)
        val budgetAdapter = BudgetAdapter(this)

        val toolbar = binding.toolbar.root
        toolbar.title = "Budget"
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        binding.apply {
            rvBudget.apply {
                adapter = budgetAdapter
                setHasFixedSize(true)
            }
        }
        viewModel.budgets.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            if(it.isNotEmpty()){
                binding.rvBudget.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.tvNoBudget.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }else{
                binding.rvBudget.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.tvNoBudget.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            budgetAdapter.submitList(it)

        }

        binding.btAddBudget.setOnClickListener {
            val action = BudgetFragmentDirections.actionBudgetFragmentToNewBudgetFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must show full of your codes.. Cant figure out what is written where like this..

Comment: where is budgetAdapter.submitList method implemented? why you dont put your codes as a whole ? we cannot help you in such way.

Comment: sumbitList is a method of listAdapter. I didn't write it myself.

Comment: How do you implement your `addBudget` method in your `ViewModel`? Make sure to create a new budget list every time you add a budget. When you add a new budget to the current budgets that is already submit to `budgetAdapter` the `DiffUtil` will treat it as the same list that's why your list wont update. This happen because in Java/Kotlin when you pass a `List` as a parameter, it passes by reference.

Comment: @SovathnaHong viewmodel uses repository, and repository uses dao to add a new budget. And dao uses room's insert method. i need to update budgets every time user adds a transaction not a budget. how can update all the budgets when the user does that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this budget is like a grand total of all transactions? And there is only one budget?

Comment: no there is different budgets

Comment: Did you try to call notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: @SovathnaHong no there are categories, and the user can create a budget for one specific category. and when user spends money on that category, budget item's amountSpent should change

Comment: @NDroidev yeah i did try. it didn't work

Comment: it is difficult to find problem.. But You can find it.. Just use logger to log every step.. And use debugger if needed.. Maybe you can figure out it.. I cant help you without running your code.. Sorry.. If you cant find it maybe you can send whole project to me and I can fix the problem via runnning it directly..

Comment: Where you update the update? post your code in github repository. It's not easy to find out without code. 90% chance you missed notifyDataSetChange() after data updation

Comment: actually there is no need to notifyDataSetChanged when using submitList function as I saw in the documentation. @Ranjithkumar

Comment: @NDroidev weird!!! Share me the documentation. show me the submitList()

Comment: This usually breaks at when we add new data to the Adapter (in your case submitList() - even though I see multiple ppl wanted to see that method, you have yet to post it). DiffUtil will check the data set you already have and will also check the new one you're adding.

Comment: @Ranjithkumar       https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#:~:text=While%20using%20a%20LiveData%20is%20an%20easy%20way%20to%20provide%20data%20to%20the%20adapter%2C%20it%20isn%27t%20required%20%2D%20you%20can%20use%20submitList%20when%20new%20lists%20are%20available.

Comment: @jane Can you please try this snippet when `budgets` live data updates? `budgetAdapter.submitList(it.toList())`
Another side note: During diff util check, compare it by triple equals (===) to check both value and reference

Comment: @jane Have you added the linear layout manager for recyclerview? Otherwise, it will not render data

Comment: @JeelVankhede i tried this. didn't work tho

Comment: @LukášAnda yes, i have

Comment: @Ranjithkumar as it's a private project unfortunately i cannot post its link here

Comment: @jane try checking if the data even arrived from the observer (by using a logging line), if not, the issue is in liveData, if yes, issue is in the recyclerview.

Comment: Is Budget model is kotlin data class . it might be due to your diff utill please debug that. check Ids which you are assigning

Comment: @Deepak yes it is a data class. couldn't find a problem with diffutil with debugging

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that your Budget Class is a data class, then the content comparison should work, so we should not have any problems with the object itself that is being used by the Adapter and the DiffUtil.

But:

I can't see the ViewModel Code - are you submitting the same List Instance to the Adapter with **submitList**? For example, are you mutating the items in a private List in the ViewModel and posting the same List on the same Live Data everytime?

If yes, then this is probably the reason why the items in the RecyclerView are not being refreshed. You need to create a new Instance of the List, with the content of the old List and then post this on the LiveData.

[image]

Example ViewModel, if you don't want to override the behavior of "submitList" where you clear the previous data and add the new one and then call by yourself notifiyDatasetChanged()

```kotlin
class MyBudgetViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // Important that its a data class, to actually have a content sensistive equals comparison

    // if you don't have an ID, you have to work with list indexes when finding
    // and updating this item
    data class Budget(val id: Int, val amount: Double)

    private val _budgets = MutableLiveData<List<Budget>>()
    val budgets: LiveData<List<Budget>>
        get() = _budgets


    init {
        _budgets.value = listOf(Budget(1, 20.0))
    }

    fun onBudgetChanged(id: Int, newBudget: Double) {
        // depends on your setup and how you fill the initial list, this maybe should never be null
        // by the time you call onBudgetChanged or something similar
        val oldList = _budgets.value ?: emptyList()

        // unused example variable - if you want to copy the list 1 by 1, ArrayList takes another list as Constructor 
        val newListUnchanged = ArrayList(oldList)

        // map returns a new instance of the list.
        val newList = oldList.map { oldItem ->
            if (oldItem.id == id) {
                oldItem.copy(amount = newBudget)
            } else oldItem
        }
        _budgets.value = newList
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont do anything to the list in ViewModel. how do i create a new list with old contents?

Comment: I wrote you some code in the answer, I hope it helps, otherwise you could override submitList in your Adapter, to manipulate the old backing List of the Adapter and then call notifyDatasetChanged() by yourself.